# Meaning of -O2 flag of GNU g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

I have one weird problem with g++ compiler. When program is compiled just with g++ main.cpp it gives one result and when I put -O2 flag it gives different output. Why is that ?

Comment: Almost certainly because you're using undefined behavior, but since you haven't shown any code, no one can possibly tell you.

Answer (score 11):

> Meaning of -O2 flag of GNU g++ compiler

The `-O` or `-Ox` (where `x` is a number like `1`, `2`, or `3`) is an optimization level. The absence of `-O` or `-Ox` means no optimizations. `-O` is equivalent to `-O1`. See [Options That Control Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

---

> When program is compiled just with g++ main.cpp it gives one result and when I put -O2 flag it gives different output. Why is that ?

As Wooble said, you have undefined behavior in your program. The compiler is free to do what it wants when it encounters undefined behavior, including compiling the statements you hoped for, dropping the undefined behavior, or making [demons fly out you nose](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/comp.std.c/ycpVKxTZkgw/S2hHdTbv4d8J).

Intel's ICC compiler is particularly ruthless about dropping code with undefined behavior. I've seen code flawlessly execute its self tests with Clang, Comeau, GCC and MSVC; and fail them when compiled with ICC due to undefined behavior.

If you have code that's mysteriously failing (like yours), then you should run it under Clang and its sanitizers. In particular, the UB sanitizer (invoked with the `-fsanitize=undefined` flag, just like `-g` or `-O` options). You will get a message on `stderr` each time your program does something it should not. You can see the full set of sanitizers available at Clang's [Controlling Code Generation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation).

You can usually install Clang from a distro's repos. If you need to download and install the latest Clang, then see Python's [Dynamic Analysis with Clang](https://docs.python.org/devguide/clang.html). The document takes you through all the steps, from downloading and installing to running your program with the sanitizers.

Here's some more reading on Undefined Behavior from the folks who write the LLVM compiler (Clang is a front-end to it):

- [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)
- [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #2/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html)
- [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #3/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)

And Dr. Regehr's blogs on Undefined Behavior (thanks Nemanja):

- [A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 1](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)
- [A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 2](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/226)
- [A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 3](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232)

Comment: Oh, another link on this: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: @NemanjaBoric - yes, Dr. Regehr's wrote the original Integer Overflow Checker (IOC). Back in the Clang 3.0 days, we had to build Clang and the checker ourselves through patches. It was later subsumed into Clang and now available using `-fsanitize=integer`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! As not clang user, I didn't know that, so that gives even more credibility to this post . And, now I've noticed that it's actually linked in the first link you've originally posted :).